# Problema al digitar una letra cuando se espera un numero en C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, switch

estoy haciendo un programa el cual consiste en hacer un menú para registrar y borrar productos de una tienda, apenas voy diseñando el menú con un switch, todo funciona bien hasta ahí, el problema es que cuando ingreso como dato algo que no sea un numero (letra o símbolo) la consola se vuelve loca; todo el texto se pone a parpadear y no me deja hacer nada (como si estuviera en un bucle) y lo tengo que cerrar.

Hay alguna manera de evitar esto? o sea que cuando ingrese una letra o símbolo automáticamente me lo detecte como no valido y me muestre el mensaje sin que la consola se vuelva loca?

Por cierto, uso Visual Studio.

Gracias de antemano : )

```
#include<iostream>
#include<locale.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");
    int opc;

    cout << "                Bienvenido a la tiendita \"Abarrotes\" ";
    cout << endl;
    

    cout << "\n1.- Alta de orden.";
    cout << "\n2.- Borra orden.";
    cout << "\n3.- Lista de ordenes generadas.";
    cout << "\n4.- Salir";
    cout << endl;
    cout << "\n¿Que deseas hacer hoy?: "; cin >> opc;

    switch (opc)
    {

    case 1:cout << "\nAlta de orden"; break;
    case 2:cout << "\nBorrar orden"; break;
    case 3: cout << "\nLista de ordenes generadas"; break;
    case 4:exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    default:
        
        if ((opc != 1) && (opc != 2) && (opc != 3) && (opc != 4))
        {

            system("cls");

                cout << "La opcion ingresada no es valida, intentalo de nuevo";
                return main();


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando tu le pides a `cin` un entero:

```
int dato;
std::cin >> dato;
```

Y el usuario, por error o a propósito, introduce una letra, suceden dos cosas:

- Se activa el flag de error en `cin`. Este flag hace que `cin` se bloquee.
- La letra se mantiene en el el buffer de entrada.

Así pues, para reestablecer el sistema debemos cumplir con dos requisitos diferentes:

- Resetear el flag de error de `cin`.
- Eliminar los caracteres que haya en `cin`.

Dicho y hecho:

```
int dato;
while(true)
{
    std::cin >> dato;
    if( !cin.good() )
    {
        // Se resetea el flag de error
        std::cin.clear();
  
        // Descartamos los caracteres que haya en el buffer de entrada  
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');
    }
    else
    {
      break;
    }
}
```

No existe un método `clear` para `cin` que deje el buffer de entrada inmaculado. En su lugar tenemos el método `ignore`. A este método hay que indicarle cuántos caracteres queremos descartar y un caracter de *parada*, es decir, `ignore` descartará `x` caracteres salvo que antes se encuentre con el caracter `Y`.

Pues bien, no tenemos forma, a priori, de saber cuántos caracteres habría que descartar y es por ello que utilizamos `numeric_limits`. Esta plantilla es la forma en la que C++ nos provee de información acerca de los tipos básicos. En este caso estamos recuperando el número más alto que *entra* en un `int`.

Comment: `std::cin.reset()` no existe, para limpiar el flag de error es `std::cin.clear()`

Comment: @Pablochaches cierto, me lié

Comment: Por fin pude teclear una letra sin que se volviera loca la consola pero ahora solo me detecta valores entre 1 y 4, si pongo algún otro valor el programa no hace nada xd

Puse la solución dentro de un if para que me detectara si es una letra o no con el isalpha, en caso de que no fuera una letra se va supuestamente al else pero por alguna razon no me lo detecta, ya probe de diferentes maneras tanto afuera como dentro del switch incluyendo con el isalnum y sigue sin detectarlo. saben porque pasa esto?

Comment: añadí el código en una nueva respuesta

Answer (score -1):

puedes la funcion atoi() o `IsDigit() !isDigit(n) ? //haga el proceso : error`, Basicamente es si is digit falla es porque es un string sino es porque es un numero [Aqui esta el uso de IsDigit](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/ctype.h/isdigit)

Comment: Esto solo funciona si en vez de leer un entero lees un string y, posteriormente, quieres evaluar si ese string es convertible a números. Además `isdigit` solo comprueba un caracter, por lo que tendrías que ir caracter a caracter

Comment: @eferion eso es lo que el quiere una manera de hacerlo, c no es python ni lenguajes modernos hay funciones que el puede limitar el tamaño de el string pero el no pregunto eso

Comment: efectivamente, el OP se está quejando que si introduce letras en vez de números, el programa entra deja de responderle y entra en bucle. Y el origen del problema es que un `int` no admite caracteres, si haces `std::cin >> entero` ahí no puedes usar `isdigit()` ni ninguna otra función porque todo lo gestiona la sobrecarga del operador `>>`

Answer (score -1):

El problema es que no estás limpiando `std::cin`, además de que estás invocando recursivamente a `main()`, donde vuelves a utilizar `std::cin` que no está limpio (tiene un failbit provocado por ingresar un no-número cuando se pide un dato numérico). Además hay una parte del código que es reduntante

```
switch (opc)
    {

    case 1:cout << "\nAlta de orden"; break;
    case 2:cout << "\nBorrar orden"; break;
    case 3: cout << "\nLista de ordenes generadas"; break;
    case 4:exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    default:
        
        if ((opc != 1) && (opc != 2) && (opc != 3) && (opc != 4))
        {

            system("cls");

                cout << "La opcion ingresada no es valida, intentalo de nuevo";
                return main();


        }
    }
```

Si no entra en el `case 1`, `case 2`, `case 3`, `case 4`, se va al default, donde compruebas nuevamente si el valor no es 1, 2, 3 o 4, lo cual es redundante pues ya es un hecho que si entró al default no va a tener esos valores.

Por último para limpiar `std::cin` puedes utilizar [`std::cin.clear()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear). Específicamente puedes utilizarlo antes de invocar recursivamente a `main()`, aunque recomiendo que no se haga de manera recursiva sino iterativa, es mucho mejor. También recomiendo utilizar [`std::cin.fail()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail) para verificar si se ingresó un valor inválido, en lugar de hacerlo con un switch.

Comment: En un `switch`, la etiqueta `default` únicamente se ejecutará cuando no haya coincidido el valor con el de ningún `case` o cuando no uses los pertinentes `break`. Ese `if` que has puesto en tu código es totalmente innecesario. Por otro lado ... ¿Dónde se supone que estás limpiando `std::cin`?